# Regex - How to match one pattern at a time

Tags: php, regex

I've this function that parses some content to retrieve homemade link tag and convert it to normal link tag.

Possible input:

```
<p>blabalblahhh <moolinkx pageid="121">text to click</moolinkx> blablabah</p>
```

Output :

```
<p>blabalblahhh <a href="whateverpage.htm">text to click</a> blablabah</p>
```

Here is my code:

```
$regex = '/\<moolinkx pageid="(.{1,})"\>(.{1,})\<\/moolinkx\>/';
preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $matches );
```

It works perfectly well if there is only one  in the string. But as soon as there is a second one, it doesn't work.

Input:

```
<p>blabalblahhh <moolinkx pageid="121">text to click</moolinkx>  blablabah.</p>
<p>Another <moolinkx pageid="128">text to clickclick</moolinkx> again blablablah.</p>
```

That's what I got when I print_r($matches):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <moolinkx pageid="121">text to click</moolinkx>  blablabah.</p><p>Another <moolinkx pageid="128">text to clickclick</moolinkx>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 121">text to click</moolinkx>  blablabah.</p><p>Another <moolinkx pageid="128
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => text to clickclick
    )

)
```

I'm not at ease with regex, so it must be something very trivial... but I can't pinpoint what it is :(

Thank you very much in advance!

NB: This is my first post here, though I've been using this terrific Q&A for ages!

Comment: Make your regex non-greedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative Regex:
`$regex = '/<moolinkx pageid="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/moolinkx>/';`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/sI3wK5

Comment: Fantastic! that was quick... it works beautifully. Thank youuuu

Comment: Fails if there are any tags in the link, eg: `<moolinkx pageid="122">Some text <em>with emphasis</em> to link</moolinkx>`

Comment: of course it fails @GarethCornish... regex is not for parsing HTML, this is a specific case

Answer (score 1):

You are using a greedy selector, which is recognising everything between the first openning tag and the last closing tag as the content between the tags. Change your regex to:

```
$regex = '/\<moolinkx pageid="(.+?)"\>(.+?)\<\/moolinkx\>/';
preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $matches );
```

Notice the `.{1,}` has changed to `.+?`. The `+` means one or more instances, and the `?` tells the regex to select the fewest characters it can to fulfil the expression.